# Is there a Kotlin compiler which creates an Android application?

Tags: android, compiler, kotlin

I'm trying gradle with android-sdk and adb on Ubuntu, following the tutorial on this page :
https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/10/basic-android-without-an-ide

I eventually got as far as sending the "Hello World!" application to the android device, where it crashed without explanation.

So I'm looking for something better. I would like a compiler which creates an application from kotlin code, without all the fuss. It's for my kid, so I wouldn't mind if it only functions on this specific android device and similar ones.

I even checked on the Google Play Store. There are kotlin compilers but they send their output to some sort of terminal emulator, within the kotlin application, they don't create a new application. And anyway I wouldn't want to write code without a proper keyboard and a large screen.

An alternative would be to transfer my javascript programs to the android device and run them in a browser. Setting the home page of this browser to my index.html should do the trick (with some adjustments).

But there's got to be a better way. And after doing a short tutorial, I think I rather fancy kotlin. I've written quite a lot of vanilla javascript and I wouldn't mind moving on to something else.

All suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I've given up on that tutorial. I found a method which functions, Apache Cordova. The code is javascript, not kotlin, but so far it seems promising.